# Most efficent way to copy data from a C++ vector to a numpy array using Boost::Python

Tags: python, c++, numpy, boost

I'm working with Boost::Python to export some data from a C++ DLL to a Python script using a Python module, but I can't find a great way to do it without resorting to copying everything over to it. This is problematic as I am working with a very large dataset and want to avoid copying data as much as possible.

I'd like to avoid the use of the vector altogether, however that would require a lot of restructuring since due to the nature of the problem I don't know how much space I'll need in advance over.

Here's an example of my code:

```
    boost::python::list return_list;

    // Run the analysis for every data point a
    for (int a = 0; a < Data.size(); a++) {

            // Results is a vector of floats of unknown size
            auto results = Data.RunAnalysis(a);

            // Create numpy array to hold data from results
            auto nparray = np::empty(make_tuple(results.size()), np::dtype::get_builtin<float>()); 

            // Copy data results data_set to numpy array
            for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); i++)
                nparray[i] = results[i];

            // Append to the return list
            return_list.append(nparray);
        }
    return return_list;
```

Any help or insight into this problem is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `std::copy`? Also maybe look up `std::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: `np.ndarray` can construct a numpy array with an existing data buffer.  I don't know what's the equivalent with `boost`, or whether your `results` qualifies as a buffer.  Looking at `boost` docs: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/python/doc/html/numpy/reference/ndarray.html

Comment: It should be possible to do without any copying at all. I've done that successfully with pybind11, don't know about boost::python though.

Comment: Is the C# comment a typo? You didn't mention .NET anywhere.

Comment: @hpaulj If I use boost::python's from_object function, the memory used by the numpy array will get destroyed when the function returns since the vector is cleaned up when it goes out of scope. I specifically need to transfer ownership from the vector to the numpy array.

Comment: @parktomatomi that is a typo, yes.